# How to start a while loop on GUI button press?

Tags: python, user-interface, button, while-loop, tkinter

I'm looking for a way to start a while loop on press of a button in this case the button named "start_loop". I'd very much like to know how this is done and would appreciate any help in finishing this thank you!

---

Here is the complete Python Script:

```
from tkinter import *
import win32api
import win32con
from tkinter import messagebox


# defining click as setting the position and starting a click and ending a click
def click(x, y):

    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0,  0)

# Creation of the GUI below

root = Tk()
root.geometry('315x250+250+250')  # 315x250 and 250 pixels in x and y direction
root.title("Buffet Time's Auto-Clicker")

# Click
click_label = Label(text='Enter # of clicks here:', fg='green').place(x=30, y=30)
click_entry = Entry().place(x=150, y=30)

# X
x_label = Label(text='Enter the x coordinate here:', fg='black').place(x=30, y=75)
x_entry = Entry().place(x=150, y=75)

# Y
y_label = Label(text='Enter the y coordinate here:', fg='blue').place(x=30,     y=120)
y_entry = Entry().place(x=150, y=120)

# Start the loop button
start_loop = Button(text='Press to Start', fg='yellow', bg='black').place(x=110,    y=175)


# prompts user before quitting
def on_closing():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        root.destroy()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

root.mainloop()

num_of_clicks = click_entry.get()
x_coord = x_entry.get()
y_coord = y_entry.get()


# while loop for the clicking
counter = 0
try:
    while counter < num_of_clicks:
        click(x_coord, y_coord)  # 230, 475 for cookie clicker

        if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(ord('X')):
            break
        counter += 1
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the Button constructor the "command" keyword:

```
start_loop = Button(root, text='Press to Start', fg='yellow', bg='black', command=self.myButtonHandler).place(x=110, y=175)
```

And define a function myButtonHandler(frame), which will be called every time the button is pressed so will increment the counter by 1.

Is that what you are after? The loop is buried inside root.mainloop, you don't have to write the loop yourself. Your Quit button's command should be frame.quit

Comment: What i'm attempting to do is to make this GUI which has the input for each of three variables in the while loop and then the auto-clicker starts once the button "Press to Start" is pressed and then it will keep clicking until either the number of clicks is done or on press of 'X' which kills the loop. Is there away i can embed the while loop into the button such that when the button is pressed the While loop will run?

Comment: Sounds like you need two threads - sorry, my Python is not up to that!